# Passing redux store to new window does not work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Some context:**

I have an application which uses React, Redux, react-redux. I need to open the application in a new browser window and keep the windows in sync.

I have achieved this by having the redux store as a global on the parent window. Some code:

```
const getStore = () => {
    if (window.opener)
        return window.opener.__reduxStore__;

    if (!window.__reduxStore__) {
        window.__reduxStore__ = createStore(todoApp);
    }

    return window.__reduxStore__;
}
```

**The issue:**

When opening the new window in IE 11, an trying to mutate the global state I get an `Error: Function.prototype.toString: 'this' is not a Function object`. Unfortunately I do not get a stack trace, but rather `File: eval code (11084), Line: 31, Column: 3` which leads me to

```
// add fake Function#toString for correct work wrapped methods / constructors with methods like LoDash isNative
})(Function.prototype, TO_STRING, function toString(){
  return typeof this == 'function' && this[SRC] || $toString.call(this);
});
```

It is also worth noting that in IE (unlike Chrome, or FireFox) there is a property on the redux store object `Symbol(react.element)_<11 random characters>` which is `undefined`

I have modified the redux-todos-example which showcases the issue; see diff on [GitHub](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/compare/master...calinilie:pass-store-to-new-windows)

Not really sure how to follow up on this one. Is it a Redux issue, an IE issue, a React issue regarding [Symbols](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/4832)?

Also, IE is **not** running in Protected Mode.

Comment: Did you ever get any clarity on this? I'm having a similar issue where the `store` is exposed as a global variable in `window`. In the opened window I get `window.opener` and when I call `opener.dispatch` I get this exact error.

Comment: Hey @DaveNewton, unfortunately did not get this solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple middleware for this situation. 
Which is basically use local storage to save the last action and dispatch the same action in other tabs.

https://github.com/AOHUA/redux-state-sync

Hope it will help you.